# Is it bad practice to append localization codes to images?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I'm considering assembling image name strings based on device type, orientation, and localization.

For example:

```
#define kLocalCode     NSLocalizedString(@"en", @"localization code")
```

...would result in "background_iphone_portrait_en.png" (or _es, _de, etc.)

It's faster in my workflow to do it this way instead of placing images with the same names in separate localized folders.

Are there any downsides with this method of image localization?

Answer (score 0):

First:
I found this a really creative solution. And it makes me think.

This is not really an answer but:

You can load the 'en' with the following call:

```
[NSLocale currentLocale]
```

This would result that you do not have to translate `en` to `fr`, `es` or `de`, but can take it runtime.
If there is a language you do not support, load the english version.